# How to create a variable of type that implement few interfaces (or subset of interfaces)?

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, casting, type-conversion

I have a third-party library (dll, created using C#) that contains interfaces

```
public interface I1 {
    void F1();
}
public interface I2 {
    void F2();
}
public interface I3 {
    void F3();
}
// and so on ...
```

and contains a class

```
public class C : I1, I2, I3 // ...
{
    public void F1() { }    // implement I1.F1();
    public void F2() { }    // implement I2.F2();
    public void F3() { }    // implement I3.F3();
    // and so on ...
}
```

---

I added a reference to this library in my project in VisualStudio and created an instance of class `C`

```
C c = new C();
c.F1();    // ok
c.F2();    // ok
c.F3();    // ok
```

The variable `c` allows to call the methods of all interfaces (`F1`, `F2`, `F3`, ...).

To create a variable that allows to call only methods of interface `I1`, it is enough to change the type of variable

```
    I1 c = new C();
    c.F1();    // ok
//  c.F2();    // error is ok
//  c.F3();    // error is ok
```

**But** now I want to create a variable of some type that allows to call methods of interfaces `I1`, `I2` and does not allows to call methods of other interfaces

```
    I1_I2 c = new C();
    c.F1();    // ok
    c.F2();    // ok
//  c.F3();    // error is ok
```

To do this, I created the interface

```
public interface I1_I2 : I1, I2 { }
```

However, the compiler does not allow me to make the assignment

```
I1_I2 c = new C();    // Compile error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'C' to 'I1_I2'.
```

I tried an explicit conversion

```
I1_I2 c = (I1_I2)new C();    // Runtime error : InvalidCastException was unhandled.
```

but this conversion cannot be performed, because class `C` does not implement `I1_I2` (only `I1` and `I2` separately).

---

One of the possible solutions to this problem could be a class-wrapper

```
public class Wrapper : I1_I2
{
    private C _c = new C();
    public void F1() { _c.F1(); }
    public void F2() { _c.F2(); }
}
// ---------------------------------
    I1_I2 c = new Wrapper();
    c.F1();    // ok
    c.F2();    // ok
//  c.F3();    // error is ok
```

but it means that I must implement each method from both interfaces.
This solution is unacceptable, because in fact these interfaces (`I1`, `I2`) contains a lot more methods.

---

**So my question is :** 
How to create a variable that will allow me to do this :

```
    c.F1();    // ok
    c.F2();    // ok
//  c.F3();    // error is ok
```

**?**

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to over engineer things? i mean restricting consumer access to certain functionality is a worthy cause, however, i often see my co workers trying to over interface everything,. That's to say, in my mind interfaces are best to describe commonality and shouldn't be used to much to limit access or control, especially when dirty little fingers and can cast things anyway they like.

Comment: _interfaces shouldn't be used to much to limit access or control_ - @TheGeneral, i'm agree, but there was need to prevent calls of some functions, because their execution led to the crash of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say in your question, you can use a wrapper class but you didn't like it. Another solution is to make the method that use the logic to be a generic method with some constraints.

So let say you have a method that actually look like this:

```
public void MySuperLogic()
{
    C c = new C();
    c.F1();
    c.F2(); 
    c.F3();
}
```

You don't want to allow a call to `C.F3()` method so a generic method with constraints can help by refactoring the method like below:

```
public void MySuperLogic<I>(I c) 
    where I: I1, I2 // <- The generic type parameter should implement interfaces I1 and I2.
{
    c.F1();
    c.F2(); 
    c.F3(); // <-- CS1061 : Compile time error.
}
```

CS1061 is a compile time error which tells you this:

> CS1061 'I' does not contain a definition for 'F3' and no extension
>   method 'F3' accepting a first argument of type 'I' could be found.

You can call your method like this:

```
var c = new C();
MySuperLogic(c);
```

We passed an instance of type `C` which implements `I3` with `F3()` method but because of the constraints defined in `MySuperLogic` you're not allowed to use `F3()` because it doesn't exist into `I1` and `I2`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best solution in this case is

```
public interface I1_I2 : I1, I2 { }

public class C_I1_I2 : C, I1_I2 { }

public static void Main() {
    I1_I2 c = new C_I1_I2();
    c.F1();    // ok
    c.F2();    // ok
//  c.F3();    // error is ok
}
```

[Source](http://replace.org.ua/topic/8736/)